# NERDTree window change during tab switch

Tags: vimrc, cursor-movement, plugin-nerdtree, tabbed-user-interface

Currently, when using NERDTree, I hit `Ctrl-ww` to navigate to my NERDTree window from my editing window. Then, I navigate to a file I want to open, and hit `t` to open it in a new tab. Now, when I want to go back to my old tab, the cursor still remains in the NERDTree window. Is there a way to makeit so that everytime I make a new tab, the cursor will switch from NERDTree back to the previous window?

Things I've already tried in my vimrc:

1. `autocmd TabLeave * wincmd p`
2. `autocmd BufLeave * wincmd p`
3. `BufWinLeave * wincmd p`

For context, I'm using gVim.